# How do I convert my CSS hex code color variable into rgba to add opacity?

Tags: css, sass

I'm working on a website project which uses a Typo3 CMS. In backend it's possible to choose a color, which changes certain elements. This is defined in a variable `--page-color`. This color code must be in hex. I have no problems with most elements, but I want to add opacity to the background color of one element and it doesn't work. I'm using Sass to compile into one main.css file.

This is the working standard version in my .scss file:

```
.textbox{
background-color: var(--page-color);
}
```

To add opacity I tried a few things like:

```
background-color: rgba(var(--page-color), 0.8);
```

and

```
$hexColor: var(--page-color);
$rgbColor: rgb(red($hexColor), green($hexColor), blue($hexColor));
$rgbaColor: rgba($rgbColor, 0.8);

background-color: $rgbaColor;
```

When compiling, the latter gives me an error:
throw new Error("Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):\nSassError: argument `$color` of `red($color)` must be a color, in function `red`
$rgbColor: rgb(red($hexColor), green($hexColor), blue($hexColor));

I think that's because the variable `var(--page-color)` is defined in the backend?
How can I work around this?

Comment: you can add opacity to hex as well by using a 4 digit or 8 digit hex value

Comment: `background-color: transparentize($hexColor, .8);`

Comment: unfortunately you cannot use `css` variables inside `sass`'s builtin functions. And also why should the color must be in hex format ??

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding a pseudo class with ::before.

So now it looks like this:

```
.textbox{
&::before{
background-color: var(--page-color);
opacity: 0.8;
}}
```